# Iteration through list of vectors - how to combine with vector iteration

Tags: r, list, for-loop, vector, lapply

I'm trying to iterate through a list of vectors to make tables of the elements in each vector. The easiest case is for considering the entire vector:

```
ls <- list(x = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 5,replace=T), 
    y = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 5, replace=T), 
    z=sample(LETTERS[1:5], 5, replace=T)
)

ls
$x
[1] "B" "A" "D" "A" "E"

$y
[1] "A" "D" "A" "D" "A"

$z
[1] "B" "C" "A" "E" "E"

lapply(ls, function(VEC) {table(factor(VEC, levels = LETTERS[1:5]))})
$x

A B C D E 
2 1 0 1 1 

$y

A B C D E 
3 0 0 2 0 

$z

A B C D E 
1 1 1 0 2
```

But when I try to make overlapping tables of subsets of the VEC, I get zilch:

```
lapply(ls, function(VEC) {
    for (i in 1:3) {
        table(factor(VEC[i:(i+2)], levels = LETTERS[1:5]))
    }
})

$x
NULL

$y
NULL

$z
NULL
```

What can I do to get 3 tables for each, x,y and z? (From 1:3, 2:4, and 3:5 of VEC)?
Thank you!

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to use variable names that correspond to base R functions. In this case `ls` typically returns all the variable names in your environment.

Comment: Also, your for loop solution does not work because that for loop doesn't actually return anything. You are calling `table` three times but they aren't going anywhere. Your function doesn't have a return value.

Comment: I agree with @MrFlick, although R will be able to tell apart function and 'data'. This is more of a human-readability concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just figured out one possible way, though I don't understand why I don't get an out-of-bounds error when I run the following without the -2:

```
ls2<-lapply(ls, function(VEC) {
    lapply(1:(length(VEC)-2), function(S) {
        table(factor(VEC[S:(S+2)], levels = LETTERS[1:5]))
     })
})

ls2

$x
$x[[1]]

A B C D E 
1 1 0 1 0 

$x[[2]]

A B C D E 
2 0 0 1 0 

$x[[3]]

A B C D E 
1 0 0 1 1 


$y
$y[[1]]

A B C D E 
2 0 0 1 0 

$y[[2]]

A B C D E 
1 0 0 2 0 

$y[[3]]

A B C D E 
2 0 0 1 0 


$z
$z[[1]]

A B C D E 
1 1 1 0 0 

$z[[2]]

A B C D E 
1 0 1 0 1 

$z[[3]]

A B C D E 
1 0 0 0 2
```

Comment: The out-of-bounds error is because VEC is of length 5 for each element of the list. If you let `S` go for from 1 to 5, then the range `S:(S+2)` could go up to `5:7` and there are no elements 6 and 7, hence the out-of-bounds error.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I would expect, but it does NOT happen! I can let S go to 100, and get no error...

Comment: Sorry, I misread that. That's right. R will let you specify any index for a vector and if it doesn't exist yet, it simply returns `NA` and table usually ignores `NA` unless you get `useNA="ifany"` or `useNA="always"`

Comment: Ah, ok! That makes sense, my expectation was off. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, because for loops don't have any sort of return value. So nothing was returned from the function that he/she passed to `lapply`. Here the function you supply to `lappy` has `table()` as it's last call so it returns that resulting table. Your function has a return value.